# Position div horizontally center but slightly to the left

Tags: html, css

Please see the image below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YINwc.jpg)

I want to center the div horizontally but have it slightly to the left of the page. The problem is that I want the div to center horizontally and vertically when the window is minimized to the phone size.

```css
<style>

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.profile {
  width: 480px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="profile">

    <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At corporis voluptatibus officiis? Minus architecto voluptatum ea enim eos exercitationem perferendis quae necessitatibus rerum mollitia, atque doloremque obcaecati unde officia soluta?</p>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes and no. I need the div to be positioned to the center-left of the page when viewed on desktop, which I can do, with the solution you provided but when you jump to mobile I want the div to jump to the center of the page.

Comment: Now you got all informations and code snippets you need to fit the code to your needs and find a solution you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this inside `.profile`

`margin: auto;`

and the div center horizontally.

But your code is not responsive, because of the fixed width  `width: 480px;` in
`.profile`

```css
<style>

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.profile {
  width: 480px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile">
    <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At corporis voluptatibus officiis? Minus architecto voluptatum ea enim eos exercitationem perferendis quae necessitatibus rerum mollitia, atque doloremque obcaecati unde officia soluta?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this for **center the div vertically and horizontally**
Run and view the snippet in fullscreen.

But you still have to change the code to your needs.

```css
<style>

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.profile {
  width: 480px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile">
    <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At corporis voluptatibus officiis? Minus architecto voluptatum ea enim eos exercitationem perferendis quae necessitatibus rerum mollitia, atque doloremque obcaecati unde officia soluta?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this for responsive your div on different devices, you don't need the container outside because the position of `.profile` is `absolute`, you can place this everywhere(alone) in your html code.

Change the code to your needs.

```
    <style>

    .profile {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
      background-color: lightblue;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    </style>

      <div class="profile">
        <p class="about">CONTENT</p>
      </div>
```

You can make the use of the `z-index` in css.

**The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.**

```
    <style>

    .profile {
    ....
      z-index: 100;
    ....
    }
 </style>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

**UPDATE FOR**(I need the div to be positioned to the center-left of the page when viewed on desktop, but when you jump to mobile I want the div to jump to the center of the page)

Try this and fix the min-width for the desktop, too your needs:

`@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)`

```
<style>

.profile {
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 background-color: lightblue;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
 .profile {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
}
</style>

 <div class="profile">
   <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At corporis voluptatibus officiis? Minus architecto voluptatum ea enim eos exercitationem perferendis quae necessitatibus rerum mollitia, atque doloremque obcaecati unde officia soluta?</p>
 </div>
```